# Can I get WCF 4 REST service endpoint working just via web.config?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm figuring out WCF/REST stuff. My target it to create service whose endpoint will have no extension, so I've created a simple WCF service:

```
namespace SampleWebSite 
{
    [ServiceContract()]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ContactService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "all", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        public string[] Sample()
        {
            return new string[] { "Bill Gates", "Paul Allen", "Steve Ballmer" };
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'd like its function to be available through URLs that make sense, like http://localhost/samplewebsite/ctsvc/all . I can reach this easily by placing following code into Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes();
}

void RegisterRoutes() 
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ctsvc", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SampleWebSite.ContactService)));
}
```

Now I'm trying to find out if I can get rid of this code and move all the magic into web.config file. I've been stuck with this for a couple of days without any result. My current configuration is following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="SampleWebSite.ContactService" behaviorConfiguration="Meta">
        <endpoint name="rest"
              address="ctsvc"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="SampleWebSite.ContactService"
              behaviorConfiguration="REST" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Meta">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="ctsvc" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Removing code from Global.asax and using this configuration instead leads me to getting 404 error constantly. Am I doing anything wrong?